# Overriding Prettier Configuration

Tags: javascript, prettier

I have an object that I am defining in a `js` file.  I would like the object to look a certain way -- but prettier changes it.

Here is how I would like it to look:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup
    .string('Enter a name')
    .required('Name is required'),
  email: Yup
    .string('Enter your email')
    .email('Enter a valid email')
    .required('Email is required'),
  password: Yup
    .string('')
    .min(8, 'Password must contain at least 8 characters')
    .required('Enter your password'),
  confirmPassword: Yup
    .string('Enter your password')
    .required('Confirm your password')
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Password does not match'),
})
```

Here is how prettier reformats it:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string('Enter a name').required('Name is required'),
  email: Yup.string('Enter your email')
    .email('Enter a valid email')
    .required('Email is required'),
  password: Yup.string('')
    .min(8, 'Password must contain at least 8 characters')
    .required('Enter your password'),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string('Enter your password')
    .required('Confirm your password')
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Password does not match'),
})
```

Is there anything that I can do to indicate to prettier to keep my formatting?  If so, how?

Comment: I had the same requirement. Googled a lot and deactivated prettier in the end. I hope someone has an answer.

Comment: comment `// prettier-ignore` if you want to retain next block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `// prettier-ignore` comment before your assignment to exclude it from formatting

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I need.  But that raises another question -- how can I get prettier to start working again after this code block?  Also, is it possible to have prettier ignore only certain rules while implementing the rest?

Comment: Comment `//prettier-ignore` exclude from the formatting only one statement, you don't need to do anything to turn it on after this one statement - it would work by default.
There is no configuration options to turn some of the rules off. You can look at all configuration options [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)